# Reusable Button Directive

Tags: angularjs, button, directive

I got 2 buttons with different functions and name, but the classes are the same. Can I create a directive for the buttons?

```
<div class="sub l">
    <button class="b week" ng-click='manageDay(cAdd, cSub = cSub + 7)' ng-model="cSub" ng-init='cSub=0'>substract a week/button>
</div>

<div class="sub l">
    <button class="b day" ng-click='manageDay(cAdd, cSub = cSub + 1)' ng-model="cSub" ng-init='cSub=0'>substract a day</button>
</div>
```

How can I create a button directive out of this? I would like something as:

```
<div substract-button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', [ ]);
  
  app.directive('telSavebutton', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
   
        template: '<button type="submit" ng-click="onFormSubmit()" >directive button</button>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            onSubmit: '&',
    onFormSubmit: '&'     
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            scope.submit = function(){
                scope.onSubmit();
            }
        }
    }
});  
   
app.controller('testCntler', ['$scope', '$location',  function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.testcontroller=function()
  {
    alert("Working")
  }
  
  }]);
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@~1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" data-ng-app="testApp"  > 

<form novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()"  ng-controller="testCntler" >
    
<table width="293" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="127">First Name</td>
    <td width="150"> <input type="text"  ng-model="fname" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mid Name</td>
    <td> <input type="text"  ng-model="mName" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td> <input type="text"  ng-model="lName" ></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <button type="submit" ng-click="testcontroller()" >Static button</button> 
    <tel-Savebutton check-Id="firstName" on-form-submit="testcontroller()"></tel-Savebutton></td></td>
   </tr>    
</table>  
                 
 </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create directive please see example :

Your view:

```
<div substract-button action="manageDay(cAdd, cSub = cSub + 1)">Substract a day</div>
<div substract-button action="manageDay(cAdd, cSub = cSub + 1)">Substract a week</div>
```

Directive:

```
  app.directive('substractButton', [

  function substractButton() {


    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,

      template: '<button class="b day"  ng-transclude ng-click="action()"></button>',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {

        action: '&onSubstract'

      }


    }

  }
]);
```

and here is [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IDGMtObT5eLDxyT6o9dY?p=preview):

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can make directives configurable as much as you want:

```
    <div substract-button date='date' type="week"></div>
    <div substract-button date='date' type="day"></div>
```

And directive:

```
.directive('substractButton', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                date: '=date',
                type: '@type'
            },
            restrict:'A',
            link:function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.substractVal = 0;
                if ($scope.type === "week") {
                    $scope.substractVal = 7;
                } else if ($scope.type === "day") {
                    $scope.substractVal = 1;
                }

                $scope.manageDay = function() {
                    var result = new Date($scope.date);
                    result.setDate($scope.date.getDate() - $scope.substractVal);
                    $scope.date = result;
                }
            },
            template: "<div class='sub l'>" +
            "<button class='b' ng-class='type' ng-click='manageDay()' ng-model='date'>substract a {{type}}</button>" +
```

""};

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oburakevych/rafJx/17/

Comment: yes Thank you for you answer. I used a piece of your code. Could you explain what the = and @ are?

Comment: @Mike Basically I created an isolated scope. "=" applies two-way binding to your scope variable in the directive and the parent (where directive was called from), while "@" just passes value of the parent's scope variable and doesn't change if the parent variable changes. You can read more on the Angularjs web site https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive see 'Isolating the Scope of a Directive' section.